# EVE - define custom flask controllers

Tags: python, rest, flask, eve

I'm using EVE for couple of days to create my own REST API but I want to have custom Flask Controller integrated with EVE is there any possibility to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok I will answer my own question. After reading more about Eve, you can use any of Flask's methods because Eve is simply inheriting from the Flask class. For example, you can do this:

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

@app.route("/x")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There's more info at the Flask documentation site here: [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: that's right. You can mark your own question as solved, so other people will see it.

Comment: `eve` documentation has this [snippet](http://python-eve.org/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html), showing how to use `flask` blueprints to do the same. It helps keep things organized when growing bigger.