# How to process data before storing to database in python eve

Tags: python, api, flask, eve

I'm currently learning python eve framework and mongoDB database for restful API development. In eve, basic CRUD operations are done only by defining the schema in `settings.py` file. Client can send GET/POST methods and data is automatically stored into mongoDB according to the predefined schema.

What if I want to preprocess my data before inserting it into mongoDB (e.g.: Client only sends product quantity and price, then the server calculates the total amount and stores product, price and amount to the database). And what if I want to process my data before respond to client. Should we use flask controller methods(like this [EVE - define custom flask controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700113/eve-define-custom-flask-controllers)) and manually store the data to database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking two things here.

First, if you want to manipulate data already stored before responding to GET requests, what you need is `on_fetched_resource_<resource_name>` and `on_fetched_item_<resource_name>` database event hooks. You can add there the information you want to the response before it is returned:

> When a GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE method has been executed, both a on_post_ and on_post__ event is raised. You can subscribe to these events with multiple callback functions. Callbacks will receive the resource accessed, original flask.request object and the response payload.

```
def post_get_callback(resource, request, payload):
    print('A GET on the "%s" endpoint was just performed!' % resource)

def post_contacts_get_callback(request, payload):
    print('A get on "contacts" was just performed!')

app = Eve()

app.on_post_GET += post_get_callback
app.on_post_GET_contacts += post_contacts_get_callback

app.run()
```

See documentation here: http://python-eve.org/features.html#post-request-event-hooks

But if you want to process POST data before storing in database what you need is a `on_insert_<resource_name>` database event hook. You can add there the information you want to the resource before it is saved at database:

> Database event hooks work like request event hooks. These events are fired before and after a database action. Here is an example of how events are configured:

```
def add_sum(items):
    for item in items:
        item['sum'] = item['a'] + item['b']

app = Eve()
app.on_insert_item += add_sum
```

Comment: Thank you very much.This is exactly what I want.